# How is this string being stored and printed?

Tags: c

I understand what is happening when I do this more explicitly using `getchar()`, `putchar()` and a while loop; however, I was just wondering is the storing and processing of an entered string the same when the code below is executed (behind the scenes)? Is each character being stored as one element of the array "typed"? How does `scanf` do this? etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char typed[500];
    scanf("%[^\tEOF]", &typed);

    printf("%s", typed);
    return(0);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `void main(void)` is bad. Although many compilers allow it, its not covered by the C standard, so its not portable. I think the C++ standard even forbids it, as it mandates that main have return type `int` (but I avoid C++ enough to not be sure about that).

Comment: The 1998 C++ standard (and probably its amendments, and the 2011 standard) says in §3.6.1: _An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall
have a return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation defined.
All implementations
shall allow both of the following definitions of `main`:
`int main() { /* ... */ }`
and
`int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each character is being stored as one element of the array `typed`.

Note that your scan string looks for anything except a tab, an 'E', an 'O', or an 'F'; the 'EOF' in the pattern has no connection with `EOF` returned by `getchar()` et al on end of file.  Also, your code is vulnerable to buffer overflows (hence the succinct comment from [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl)) because you don't specify the size of the buffer in the format string.  You'd be safer with:

```
scanf("%499[^\tEOF]", &typed);
```

Also, the return type of `main()` is `int`, not `void`.

Comment: No: the character class `%[..]` and negated character class `%[^...]` are alternatives to the string `%s`.  Officially, they're called _scansets_.

Answer (score 1):

Each element gets saved as elements of array. You should not use `&` when your variables are already arrays. An array name is already an address.

`getchar()` has the default delimiter: return key and takes input as character only

while `scanf` allows various types of input by specifying the format: `%s`, `%d` etc

You can also specify the delimiter for `scanf` (default are space, tab, enter)

In your case, the delimiter is specified as tab or `EOF`.

Comment: Be careful with how you interpret 'EOF'; what you said is ambiguous.  I assume that what you mean is 'E' or 'O' or 'F' since the alternative (that it means an end-of-file indication) would be incorrect.